# Looking for a revision control system which allows signatures with X.509 certificates

Tags: version-control, dvcs, digital-signature, x509, pkcs#11

I am looking for a (distributed) revision control system which allows me to sign commits using X.509 certificates.
The systems that I am aware of which allow me to apply a digital signature to a commit (like git, bazaar, mercurial) only work with GnuPG.

One more thing I would be interested in ist to use a hardware token (via a PKCS#11 library) to sign my commits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mercurial with [CommitsigsExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CommitsigsExtension):

> Embed GnuPG and **OpenSSL signatures** directly into changesets

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that extension, I only found the gpg one. I'll look into it, thank you.

Comment: I ended up using git, manually creating the signatures and storing them in notes.